# Unable to input random numbers into an array due to Next() method

Tags: c#

```
void Rnd1 () {

    int[] array = new int[5];
    Random randNum = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i <array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = randNum.Next(min, max);
    }
}
```

Im trying to input random ints into an array and this is what ive been able to get so far, however im getting an error with the .Next part of the code. The message is "Random does not contain a definition for Next"

Comment: Make sure your `Random` is `System.Random`.

Comment: Your code works fine for me! Perhaps you're using a different class named `Random`.

Comment: As show on @mindOfAi's answer. You do not need to add `(min, max)`.

Comment: Well, he/she can if she wants. The actual problem here is that the Random class that she/he might be using is not System's Random. He/she should explicitly call System.Random to make it work.

Comment: Yes if he/she wants a range of min and max but on his/her code min and max was not defined so i think its unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for my first answer. The method is working properly for me. It seems like you have a reference that also has Random class. You should explicitly call `System.Random` to use the `Random.Next()`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm not really that busy, I think that's why.